# What changes do I have to make to my code so it also sorts negative numbers?

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>   


void countingSort(int array[], int k, int n){
    int i,j;
    int B[100],C[1000];
    for (i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
       C[i]=0;
    }
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        C[array[j]]++;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        C[i]+=C[i-1];
    }
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        B[--C[array[j]]]=array[j];
    }
    printf("Sortiran niz je: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void max(int array[], int *k,int n){
    int i;
    printf("Broj elemenata u nizu je %d\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]>*k) {
            *k=array[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(int brArg, char *arg[]){
    FILE *ulaz;
    ulaz=fopen(arg[1],"r");

    int array[1000];
    int i=0,j,k=0,n,x,m;

    while(fscanf(ulaz,"%d", &array[i])!=EOF)    
        i++;
    fclose(ulaz);
    n=i;    
    max(array,&k,n);
    countingSort(array,k,n);
    return 0;
}
```

My code works excellent for positive integers but I need to modify it so it can also sort negative integers. I hope you can help me. I don't have anything else to say but I can't post a question unless I write something here about it, so I hope it's enough.

Comment: format your code, it's unreadable.

Comment: And *never* write things like `B[--C[array[j]]]=array[j];`.  That's way too hard to follow.

Comment: Your counting sort works for integers of a certain range, at the moment [0, 1000). You don't enforce that range and having the number 2000 in the array is just as bad as a negative number. Anyway: You could find the lowest number `base` and index `C[arr[i] - base]`.

Comment: Adding to MOehm's advice, if you figure out the largest value as well as the smallest, you can dynamically allocate `C` with `malloc()`.  Then you won't have a range limitation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a linked list, the generic list Glist exists in the GObject library. If you only need to deal with 32bit integers you can use it with very little extra programming. As you read the integers from file perfom an insertion sort in that while loop.